# Entity Framework not detecting an existing table

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

i am facing some troubles with entity framework.
It seems that my code detects a table that don't actually exist in the database (Code First Generation).

Well i mentionned in my identity model code this line :

```
public virtual List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
```

in the fluent API part i did :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().ToTable("Messages");
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Messages)
        .WithRequired(c => c.SendedByUser)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Just above the Message class :

```
[Table("Messages")]
```

Still when i add a migration, the result is as below : 
[image: Code Image]

And as you can see, the migration try to use some Messages table that it didn't create yet, left side is the server explorer, where you can see the actual tables that i really have.

How can i fixe that so that EF updates my database correctly by creating automatically the Messages table without messing with it manually?

Comment: Migrations don't look at the database when generating the schema changes - they look at the model stored in the prior migration. How many prior migrations do you have? Do you have automatic migrations enabled? You may need to remove the migration prior to this one.

Comment: FYI the fluent api way to call out a table name is `ToTable("...")`

Comment: Well i do have 13 migrations before, and none of them contains a Message table creation, i checked that before posting here. Furthermore, automatic migration is disabled, so that it don't generate problems, i guess i did enable it at some moment in the project and it should had generated problems. Anyway i am trying to delete the entire database and regenerate it from my migrations then add a last migration and reupdate database to see if it will work.